# Where can I rent a car in French Guiana to cross to Suriname/Brazil?

Tags: car-rentals, borders, brazil, french-guiana, suriname

Flying to Suriname can be very expensive since the transatlantic connection is tightly controlled by the GOS. A less expensive solution is to travel to the neighboring French Guiana which is officially part of the EU. Traveling the 400 km between the two capitals can be quite a hassle. It would be convenient to rent a car and just drive yourself.

Unfortunately the main airport renting agency does not allow you to cross the border to Suriname or Brazil. Does anyone here know of a renting agency that allows EU-South American border crossing?

If there is really no renting agency, could you buy insurance for EU/South-American border crossing?

Comment: Excellent long-tail question!

Comment: I love the idea that France has a common border with Brazil...

Comment: Are you aware that French Guyana now has [long-distance buses](http://www.cg973.fr/Lignes-de-transport-prevues)? Not that “hassle” isn't justified (you'd need three buses across French Guyana, then a ferry and another bus in Suriname), but at least there's a way with a schedule. Probably more interesting than driving, if slower.

Comment: @Gilles, it would be valuable to make it an answer.

Comment: @Gilles Yes I am aware of that. That is what I meant with "hassle".   Their schedule is very "informal", making it impossible to cross the border before it closes in the evening. Renting a car might solve that.

Comment: @Andra I've just looked at http://avis.com and http://nationalcar.com.  I couldn't find any terms that restrict where you can go.  Hertz has those restrictions printed.

Comment: @Karlson They are at the airport. I have asked all major car rentals at the airport, but none allowed crossing the border. The problem is that we are practically talking about a European/South American crossing. Locals can get additional insurance to cross borders, but I guess that for car rentals with head qu

Comment: You do realize there is no land connection between the two countries, right? The [Oyapock River Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyapock_River_Bridge) is scheduled to open Real Soon Now(tm), but there's still no official opening date.

Comment: There is a scheduled ferry connection between FG and SME. Last time I was at the french/brazilian border there also was an unscheduled ferry connection between both countries. Did that ferry stop?

Answer (score 5):

The [official French Guiana tourism website](http://www.tourisme-guyane.com) lists a few [transport options (including some car rentals)](http://www.tourisme-guyane.com/en/transportation/transport.html) in the different cities and towns and their phone numbers. 
If they don't allow leaving the country then either try hitchhiking, or take a bus to a border town, cross the border and then continue with either bus or a rental car in Brazil.

If this question is still relevant and worth the long distance call, you might ring them up and ask, or send an email.

Don't forget to report back! :)

Comment: There are some on the list I still need to consult. But the many I have consulted don't allow border crossing. THere are bus connections, but these requires staying over at the border. With a car you would be able to arrive in Suriname at the same day you arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Flying into Suriname is much cheaper than flying into Cayenne. The airport taxes in Cayenne are generally sky high. Don't know where you're coming from, but going to the US from Paramaribo is half-price compared to Cayenne.

That being said, if you do find a cheaper way to get to Cayenne and then want to cross a border, it's not a big deal as long as you have the proper paperwork to be in each country. There is a list of rental car agencies at the airport [on the site of commerce chamber](http://www.guyane.cci.fr/fr/aeroport/services/loueurs_de_voitures): 
However, you would have to make arrangements to leave the car somewhere in St. Georges or St. Laurent, which could be complicated.

There are also different taxis collectifs that run around FG. You might be able to find info on those on blada.com

Lastly, as of a few months ago, there's a flight that goes from Cayenne to Parbo.

Comment: I think the question is about insurance for crossing the border, not where to fly. And the comparison of flights seem to be already done.

Comment: Whether flying to Cayenne or Paramaribo is cheaper depends on when you fly and where from. From Paris I think Cayenne is usually significantly cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Even you can get a car and cross the border to Brazil from French Guiana, I think you know you can only use this car on Amapá state. I don't know where are you going, but Amapá state does not have interconnected roads on south due to Amazon river. Take a look on the map.

If are planning to visit other places in Brazil, you can take a flight from Macapá (capital of Amapá state).